# Instance of 'list' has no 'split' member

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Tengo un problema, pero primero diré que es lo que he hecho para situarnos.

Yo he intentado utilizar el input para así obtener varios números que puede dar el usuario y poner-los en una lista, hasta ahí me va bien, me coge los números dados por el usuario y los pone en una lista.

Ahora bien el problema viene después, pero para que sea más fácil explicar el problema, pondré un ejemplo:

Si el usuario ejecuta el programa y el programa le pide que introduzca Max 3 números, el usuario lo que haría seria poner esto: `1,2,3`
ahora ya obtenidos los números, estos se tendrán que meter en una lista, `[1,2,3]` y la longitud de la lista sería 3, pero no es así.

He intentado hacer *debugging* y vi que en lugar de ser: `[1,2,3]` es: `['1,2,3']`, y la longitud es 1 y no 3, porque al parecer lo detecta como un *string*.

Así que pensé que tendría que pasarlo a *int* para poder solucionar el problema, pero al pasarlo me da este error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2,3'

Pensé otra vez y me di cuenta de que seguramente no se podría pasar a *int* porque contenía el signo de puntuación `,`. Intente utilizar él `.split()`, ahora el usuario no tendría que poner `,`, porque al obtener el número `123` se pasaría a `int(123)` y luego con él `.split()` separarlos con el signo de puntuación `,` (1,2,3) pero al utilizar el *split* de esta forma: `numero_list.split()`, me sale un error que dice:

> Instance of 'list' has no 'split' member

Esto me da a entender que la lista ¿no tiene el atributo *split*?

Ahora bien mi pregunta seria: **¿Cómo podría coger los valores que pone el usuario y pasarlos a *int* para luego separarlos con una `,` y que su longitud o `len()` sea 3 y no 1?**

Son 3 pasos para conseguirlo, no sé si habría una manera más corta, pero es la que se me ocurrió.

Aquí os dejo el código que he utilizado para hacer *debugging* y tal:

```
def numero_len():
    numero_list = []
    numeros =input("introduce numeros max 3: ")
    numero_list.append(int(numeros))

    if len(numero_list) == 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

En el código de arriba dará error en la parte de `numero_list.append(int(numeros))`, por si lo intentáis con este `input(1,2,3)`.

Gracias de Antemano!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> esto me da a entender que la lista no tiene el attributo split?

Las `string` tienen atributo split.

> da este error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2,3'. Pensé otra vez y me di cuenta de que seguramente no se podría pasar a int porque contenía el signo de puntuación (,)

Estas en lo correcto, es por las multiples comas. No se puede hacer la conversión a `int` porque python no sabe como convertir un número con varias comas.

Los pasos de tu código están bien, no entiendo porqué no te funciona el `split` en la string, tu aproach es muy bueno, mira este ejemplo con `split`:

```
def numero_len():
    numeros =input("introduce numeros max 3: ")
    numero_list = numeros.split(",")
    if len(numero_list) == 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
print(numero_len())
```

Comment: Vale ya veo, entonces tenia un poco mal entendido el concepto de .split()

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación.